# SqlServer Db in readonly mode?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Im opening an existsing db in ssms.

I generally see some sp's and tables etc.

my user pemission has full permission.

Is there anyway of openeing the DB in read only mode ( only temporary ) ? ( like a flag or something - or switch param )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that:

```
ALTER DATABASE database-name SET READ_ONLY
```

Nevertheless you should only do that if you dont want any user or automated process to change the database and are worried about the performance of the database (i.e. no locking = better performance).

If, on the other hand, you are worried about permissions - deal with the problem by setting permissions properly ofc.